# How to improve the specific columns count AWK

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, scripting

I have a big text file, it has 46 columns in total:

### INPUT

```
Column1 Column2 ... Column46
```

I need to enumerate and count how many times repeat in themselves from column 17 until the 46. For example:

**My file is like:**

```
Column17 Column18 Column19 Column20 Column21 Column22 Column23 ... Column46

Column17 Column18 Column19 Column20 Column21 Column22 Column23 ... Column46
Column17 Column18          Column20          Column22
         Column18          Column20
                           Column20
```

### Desired Output:

```
1 Column17 - 2 times
2 Column18 - 3 times
3 Column19 - 1 time
4 Column20 - 4 times
5 Column21 - 0 times
6 Column22 - 2 times
7 Column23 - 1 time
    " "    - N times
29 Column46 - 1 times
```

---

### My awk Command:

```
awk '{n=1;if(NR==1)n=25;for(i=n;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++} END{for(val in a) print val,a[val]}' filelog.txt
```

### Actual Output:

```
Column1 ... Column46
bla 1 blaN...3 bla 3 
bla 3 blaN...2 bla 5
bla 7 blaN...4 bla 7
```

Takes all and every string of the whole file and count how many times repeat themselves. 
**For example:**

```
Column1 //There are 54 lines, takes all words/strings of that column
bla 3 //The 3 and 4, is the number of repetitions.
bla 4
```

---

But my command counts **all** the columns (from the **1**, until **46**) and every phrase in themselves, and the thing I want is count from the 17 until the 46 like the **Desired Output** Is there any way to make with my same command? or is necessarily to make it by other one?

Comment: Show your actual output.

Comment: @Dip I've added more information about the Output, if you have more doubts, please ask me more about it. Thank you!

Comment: On what basis you say Column21 count is 0 and  Column19 count is 1 ?

Comment: How are the columns separated?

Comment: All the columns are separated one by each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **cat** command with **-n** option for enumeration.

And specify **n=17** as you wants to start from there.

Use following command:

```
cat -n <(awk '{n=17;if(NR==1)n=25;for(i=n;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++} END{for(val in a) print val,a[val]}' filelog.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, then this is the problem:

```
{n=1;if(NR==1)n=25;for(i=n;i<=NF;i++) ...
```

For every record except the first, you set `n=1`. Then you process all columns starting from `n`. But you actually want to set `n=17`.

Comment: It does again the same thing... start the count from the column one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: With your command starts to count from the first line to the last one. But you've helping to me, Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's not my command, that's yours. I said you need to set `n=17`.