# How to delete whitespaces in columns?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, tr

I want to filter some columns of a file, it has **46** in total.
I only want to filter from the **25** until the **46**, by the next way:

**Desired Output:**

```
Column25 Column26 ... Column47
Column25 Column26 ... Column47
Column25 Column26 ... Column47
```

I have the correct command with awk:

```
cat -n <(awk '{n=17;if(NR==1)n=25;for(i=n;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++} END{for(val in a) print val,a[val]}' filelog.txt)
```

The command above, takes from the **25** column until the last one, in this case is the **47**. It works properly, prints all the strings in all the fields I want.

---

### But there is a problem here:

The columns I would like to print have **whitespaces** like the next way:

```
Column25 Column26     ...    Column47
Column25 Column26    [...]   Column47
[:space:]Column26  [:space:] Column47
[:space:][:space:] [:space:] [:space:]
Column25 [:space:] [:space:] [:space:]
```

The problem is: **When I print all specific columns, the strings in another columns pass to the white spaces in the columns desired.**

For example:

```
Column25           Column26             ...          Column47
Column25           Stringsofcolumn12  Manystrings Stringsofcolumn21
Stringsofcolumn23  Stringsofcolumn5   ofmanycolumns Stringsofcolumn22
Column25           Stringsofcolumn16  blablabla    anothermanystrings
```

**Are any way to delete the white spaces in the columns I would like to print, to avoid this situation?**

---

### NOTE:

The strings of the columns, have the same text of the headers. example: if the `column28` has content strings, the strings are `column28` literally. But I guess that doesn't matter right now, only comment.

Thank you!

Comment: Your command produces a result as "Desired Output" in [your previous question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/461703/72456). it's unclear what you are asking here also. if you want column 17~47 to print, you don't need an array, just do `awk '{n=(NR==1? 25:17);for(i=n;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' logfile` if the columns are separated with Tab/Space

Comment: The question is clear. I don't know if you're able to see the correct question, because in that case I found I wanted. But in this case I only want to order the Strings with their columns.

Comment: @αғsнιη post your comment like answer, is the most near answer I want to solve this. Please, I want to mark like solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
cat thefile | tr '\t' ' '| tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f25-46
```

Please mark as the correct answer if that solve your problem

Comment: Almost done, but is still pasting the strings of other columns.

Comment: What other columns can you try to explain more?

Comment: Content of all columns earliest of 25. For example if I have in the column 24 a word 'dog', it will be paste in the column 25.

Comment: Do you have columns separeted by tab? Are you saying that columns 1 to 25 are show by cut? Try the new version considering columns separated by tab.

Comment: Exactly, almost columns have a tab as delimiter. But right now I can see something in the column 24, it has not any delimiter between the column 25.

Comment: So try this new version, with an additional tr command. What happen now? Are you good?

Comment: It still the same error. do you know what?? I'll try another thing, I'm gonna test the command in the αғsнιη's comment, cut the specific lines I want, and then find once again in the same file for those lines. Meanwhile I'll mark your answer like correct. Sorry, but the files I work are a big disaster!. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Please don't give up... Post the output you are getting.and what you expect

Comment: This is my Output: 
`Column25 Column26 Column27 Column28 Column29 ... Column46 
manycontent manycontent manycontent
manycontent manycontent manycontent`

My desired Output is above in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82202/discussion-between-mareyes-and-luciano-andress-martini).